# Prevent MPMoviePlayerController rotating and scaling to portrait when in fullscreen

Tags: ios, ios5, rotation, orientation, mpmovieplayercontroller

In an iOS5 application for iPhone 4/4s I have a UIViewController with an MPMoviePlayerController view added to its view:

```
[self.view insertSubview:self.fullscreenMoviePlayerController.view atIndex:2];
```

The UIViewController only supports landscape orientation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation 
{
  // Return YES for supported orientations.
  return  interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
          interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;

}
```

this correctly locks rotation to only landscape. However when I set the MPVideoPlayerController to display fullscreen, this is ignored and the video is no longer constrained to landscape and rotates to whatever orientation the phone is held in.

How can I prevent MPMoviePlayerController's video from rotating to Portrait orientations in fullscreen? It is crucial that the video does not rotate when the phone is rotated to portrait.

I have tried subclassing MPVideoPlayerController and overriding  `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` but this has no effect.

The MPMoviePlayerController is only one part of the view, so using an MPMoviePlayerViewCotroller is absolutely not an option.

Comment: What exactly you need do you need to be in always the video play in Landscape mode ? is it

Comment: Yes. I need the video to display only in landscape whether in fullscreen or not.

Comment: Are you working on iPad or iPhone?

Comment: Why not use AVPlayer and add the AVPlayerLayer to the display view instead of mucking about with MPVideoPlayerController?

Comment: @StevenVeltema If I'd known how buggy MPMoviePlayerController was when I started I would have done and I will most definitely do so on future projects, but I've got this far with it and everything else is now working fine (after an awful lot of work-arounds), so I'm loathe to abandon all that and have to build up all the UI from scratch.

Comment: Does your application (not only this viewcontroller) need to support both Landscape/Portrait modes?

Comment: @NikGreen There are sections of the app that support Portrait and sections that support landscape. No sections support both. The section containing the UIViewcontroller that contains the MPMoviePlayer supports only landscape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be rather difficult if you really want to avoid using MPMoviePlayerViewController. 
One option, that seems to work even if you have it in fullscreen, is to manually set the frame of the MPMoviePlayerController's view. 
(Note that in other iOS issues, sometimes using the background view has produced different results, but it's worth a shot).

```
MyMPMoviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, your numbers, here);
```

However, Apple, in their docs, says that the controller's frame should be set to the frame of it's parent view.

```
[MyMPMoviePlayerController.view setFrame: parentView.bounds];
```

The less elegant solution, but one that might work even if that one doesn't is this:

Listen for the UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification and take the movie player's view. Apply a transfrom, bounds, and center (or frame, etc) on it so that it still fits in the landscape view. Essentially transform it back each time it tries to rotate away. (This is all assuming that you really cannot keep it from rotating with shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:).

The only issue here is that it may keep the movie in portrait but screw around with the view, which is not the desired outcome.

Comment: Thanks those are two good plans of attack. I went down a similar path before and it was messy, but looks like there's no clean solution to this issue.

Comment: Just a thought... If you have your MPMoviePlayerController stored somewhere in a reference, you can add it to as many views as you would like. You could then listen for the MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification and present another view/UIViewController (that you disabled the rotation of) with your movie player (or probably moviePlayer.view) added to it, and that wouldn't allow rotation. Then listen for the opposite notification and dismiss your presentation.

Comment: It looks like it is possible, but the best method I have been able to find is to simply get the device rotation notifications yourself and then apply rotations (and possibly set an anchor point so that it will rotate about the center...) whenever necessary. Obviously, ignore the ones that you don't want to rotate to. By receiving the notifications about fullscreen, you will be allowed to define this behavior separately depending on the state of the movie.

Comment: I'm really confused. I thought I'd have a look up the view hierachy and I can see that the root of the rotation is well above the MPMoviePlayerControllerView. It's an instance of UINavigationTransitionView. The hierachy looks like this: MPMovieView < UIView < UIViewControllerWrappper < **UINavigationTransitionView** < UILayoutContainerView < UIWindow. With rotation occurring first in UINavigationTransitionView, about which I can find no information.

Comment: Is that view there because you're in fullscreen, or because your app has already decided that it would like to rotate?
I would bet that you still might be able to ignore rotation and implement it yourself. Messy, but it might work.

Comment: Just as an experiment, if you listen for the fullscreen notifications, have your app delegate receive those and have your whole application rotate or not depending on the fullscreen state (probably just save a bool or something in the appdelegate for this test). Does it still rotate if you turn rotation off in the appdelegate whenever you're in full screen (i.e. can you go over the head of the UINavigationTransitionView)?

Comment: Of course. Let me know if you find a way to do it, I'd love to know if it works!

Comment: I tried just about everything, then eventually realised that I could get exactly the same effect by setting the control style to fullscreen and hiding the status bar and navigation bar without actually setting fullscreen. This gave me exactly the same effect, but because it was not actually fullscreen, the player obeyed the orientations I had specified.

Answer (score 0):

yes, i saw you said using MPMoviePlayerViewController is not an option:

still … why not attempt to make MPMoviePlayerViewController of the ViewController that you have that otherwise contains the MPMoviePlayerController and the other items in your view controller.  the good part about this is that MPMoviePlayerViewController already has the MPMoviePlayerController built in.  you just refer to that instead of the MPMoviePlayerController that you have in your own viewController.  that has the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation that you can override and should do the right thing for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can prepare two videos. If there is no other choice.

Comment: This does not in any way answer my question.

Answer (score -2):

Please Visit the link this shows the video only in the landscape mode by default it does so http://mobiledevelopertips.com/video/getting-mpmovieplayercontroller-to-cooperate-with-ios4-3-2-ipad-and-earlier-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html. I hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: This link has no relevance to my question and deals with iOS3.

Comment: But you don't need to look towards SDK just check out you are inserting a movieplyaer view on self.view just try modalviewcontroller just like in the example may be you can get your thing done. And thanks for -ve the answer i was just trying to help you .

Comment: I gave your answer a down vote because 1. You didn't answer the question and just added a link. 2. The link has nothing to do with my question.